# scanf not saving values correctly

Tags: c, printf, scanf

while using scanf within a fucntion, which I have defined, to change values within an array that I have passed by referance to that function it doesn't change the value at all, while being double type.

When i change the place holder from:
scanf("%1f", &x)
to 
scanf("%d", &x)
it works as expected, but I need to use doubles for this project.

```
int main()
{
double varArray[MAX];
zeroFill(varArray);
}


void fill(double *array) {
    for(int i =0; i<MAX; i++){
    printf("what is index %d?\n", i);
    scanf("%f",(array+i));
    printf("%f \n", *(array+i));
}
```

instead of changing the value at that index it changes it to 0.000000 or a jiberish number :

```
 what is index 0?
 1
 0.000000
 what is index 1?
 2
 0.000000
 what is index 2?
 3
 -0.000000
 what is index 3?
 4
 0.000000
 what is index 4?
 5
 0.000000
 what is index 5?
 6
 0.000000
 what is index 6?
 7
```

182043948477041810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

So for the inputs 3 and 7 it has returned a -0.000000 and a v large number. 
However this isn't consistent so other inputs will give similar outputs

Comment: And please avoid pointer arrithmetic for array indexing. Use e.g. `array[i]` instead (it's *exactly* equal to `*(array+i)`).

Comment: Yep that was it! i was trying to use 1 instead of lower case L because they look the same lol

Answer (score 3):

To write the result of a `scanf` to `double`, use `%lf`. `%f` is for `float`.

Do not use `%d` with `double`. `%d` is for `int`.

(When printing, either `%lf` or `%f` may be used for either a `float` or `double`. This is because a `float` value is automatically promoted to a `double` value when calling `printf`, or when calling any function where the argument corresponds to `...` in the parameters or any function declared without a prototype.)